# TFS 2015 - How to track activity across projects

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm a architect used to work with GitHub/GitLab. There, i can click on Activity and see, on a single page, whats going on across any number of projects.

Now i'm working on a TFS 2015 company. How can I get this kind of broad view on TFS? or do I really need to go project to project, repository per repository, checking for new commits, pushes, branches, etc...

Comment: This has to do with how they have chosen to organize things. Team Projects are intended to be isolated. In addition, TFS 2015 is old and has much more limited dashboarding capabilities than TFS 2018.

Comment: So, your telling me that (as far as you know) i have to check repo by repo?

Comment: You can execute a custom query across all projects to get insight on work items. But for repos, I don't think you can have a single dashboard to do it.